# Cannot use transaction when IDbConnection.BeginTransaction is used in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: transactions, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to use transactions with ormlite but instead of using ormlite added extension method OpenTransaction, I want to use IDbConnection.BeginTransaction because I am not referencing ormlite in the project I want to manage the transactions.

So I go like:

```
    using (var dbTrans = db.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // do some work

        dbTrans.Commit();
    }
```

but this is throwing the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1de24adb938b932d\StackExchange.Profiling\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 277
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.ExecuteSql(IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.WriteExpressionCommandExtensions.Update[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, T item, Expression`1 expression)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExpressionsApi.<>c__DisplayClassd`1.<Update>b__c(IDbCommand dbCmd)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExpressionsApi.Update[T](IDbConnection dbConn, T item, Expression`1 where)
...
```

When I was debugging I noticed that the Transaction property of db object is not set after the transaction is begun. I looked into the source code [OrmLiteConnection.cs#L48](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/c0ea0f6aad27c8172931ecdbaab8da691f56fc10/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteConnection.cs#L48) and I cannot see if the transaction is ever assigned to OrmLiteConnection.Transaction.

So is this something that needs to be fixed in OrmLiteConnection.BeginTransaction or am I using BeginTransaction wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The API for opening transactions in OrmLite is `db.OpenTransaction()` which gets [assigned in the OrmLiteTransaction contructor](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/ae1d48e6284723f7f0cbc2f343265b31d3c0be0e/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteTransaction.cs#L20) and is automatically assigned to each db command created within the scope of the transaction.

If you want to use ADO.NET's native `BeginTransaction()` API, you'll need to assign it to the ADO.NET `IDbCommand` yourself, i.e:

```
using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
using (var dbTrans = db.BeginTransaction())
using (var dbCmd = db.CreateCommand())
{
    dbCmd.Transaction = dbTrans;

    // do some work
    dbTrans.Commit();
}
```